# how to count how many elements have a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filter

I am using jQuery to try and find which IDs have a certain class name. The reason this is important to me is I am using toggleClass() from jQuery to show and hide certain divs and when a button is selected I want a viewport to display or hide. I have 2 personal goals: One is to find a way to do this in jquery and the other is to understand how to do this in javascript. I understand the javascript will be much more advanced and I am prepared.

1. How can I use the resetViewport() to count the amount of "selected" classes?
2. Is there a better way to do this?
3. In javascript, how can one do this same thing? Even if you tell me specific methods in js thats ok. I am not asking for exact code. I just want to learn.

Just so there is no question I added the code. Lets start by looking at my personal hosted web page called [CodeAmend](http://www.codeamend.com/forum-questions/window-toggle-test/) and here is the code

****html***

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Code Player</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <p>CodePlayer</p>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li id="html-button" class="toggle selected no-highlight">HTML</li>
                    <li id="css-button" class="toggle selected no-highlight">CSS</li>
                    <li id="js-button" class="toggle selected no-highlight">JS</li>
                    <li id="result-button" class="toggle selected no-highlight">Result</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="run-button" class="no-select">Run</div>
        </div>

        <div id="html-container" class="code-container">
            <div class="code-label">HTML</div>
            <textarea>Code</textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="css-container" class="code-container">
            <div class="code-label">CSS</div>
            <textarea>Code</textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="js-container" class="code-container">
            <div class="code-label">JS</div>
            <textarea>Code</textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="result-container" class="code-container">
            <div class="code-label">Result</div>
            <iframe>Code</iframe>
        </div>



    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

*** here is javascript / jquery ***

```
 $("[id^=button]").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    // creates the name of a viewport ID. "view-" + html of button
    var viewID = "#view-" + $(this).html();
    $(viewID).toggle();
    resetViewport(4);
});

function resetViewport(numberOfViewports) {
    var viewSize;
    switch (numberOfViewports) {
    case 1:
        viewSize = "400px";
        break;
    case 2:
        viewSize = "198px";
        break;
    case 3:
        viewSize = "131px";
        break;
    case 4:
        viewSize = "98px";
        break;
    }
    $("[id^=view]").css("width", viewSize);
}
```

***here is css***

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.clear-fix {
    clear: both;
}
.no-highlight {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
/* why does menu margin excape parent without padding on container.. change to 0 and all margen excapes. */

#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 456px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 1px;
    background-color: #555;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
/* Menu styling */

#menu {
    width: 231px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

#menu li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #58d;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu li+li {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#menu .selected {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
}

[id^="view"] {
    width: 98px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 1px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery collections and Javascript NodeLists are both array-like, so you can use the `.length` property to get the number of elements.

jQuery:

```
resetViewport($(".selected").length);
```

Plain Javascript:

```
resetViewport(document.getElementsByClassName("selected").length);
```

Comment: Well, this really makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much. So as far as I am going about it. Is my code good or does it look like bad practice?

Comment: There's probably some pure CSS way to make the visible DIVs automatically divide the space evenly, which is what you seem to be doing. But CSS layout is not my forté,